# In React how can I access on field of a document from firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my React project I want to display a rating field from a firestore database. Doing `console.log()` of my "manager" variable, which is the docs from my database(currently just a single one) I get this:[image: database object]

Doing the same thing with "manager[0]" I get what is expected:[image: database doc]

However when I try to access the "rating field", doing `console.log()` of "manager[0].rating", when I save the file I get what I expected (The 7 in console), however when I refresh the website it doesn't load and give me some errors, such as this one:[image: console error]

I'm getting the data using this piece of code:

```
const managerCollectionRef = collection(db, "manager");
const [manager, setManager] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getManager = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(managerCollectionRef);
      setManager(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))
  }

  getManager();
}, []);
```

and calling it this way:

```
<div>
  {console.log(manager[0].rating)}
</div>
```

Does someone have an ideia of what's happening or how to solve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code you're working with.  This debug output doesn't really explain what you're doing and how you're doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `rating` before firebase has finished fetching documents from the `manager collection` using `getDocs` which is `asynchronous`.

Only after `getDocs` has finished retrieving your documents and the `manager state` has been updated will you be able to access the `rating` property.

Check if there are any documents available before accessing the `rating` property using the code below.

```
{manager.length > 0 ?
<div>
  {manager[0].rating}
</div>: <p>No documents available</p>
}
```